# Swift: Converting ISO8601 to Date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, dateformatter

Trying to convert `ISO8601` formatted `String` into `Date` and getting a `nil`.

`let dateString = "2020-06-27T16:09:00+00:00" // ISO8601`

I tried two different ways:

```
import Foundation
let df = DateFormatter()
df.timeZone = TimeZone.current
df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let toDate = df.date(from: dateString)

print("toDate \(String(describing: toDate))") // output: toDate nil
```

I also tried:

```
import Foundation
let isoDateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
isoDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
isoDateFormatter.formatOptions = [
    .withFullDate,
    .withFullTime,
    .withDashSeparatorInDate,
    .withFractionalSeconds]
let isoDate = isoDateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
print("isoDate \(isoDate)") // output: isoDate nil
```

Date format in `String` is `ISO8601`.  I validated it here: http://jsfiddle.net/wq7tjec7/14/

Can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You specify `SSS` in the date format, or `withFractionalSeconds` for the ISO formatter, but your date string does *not* have fractional seconds ...

Comment: Tip: `let dateStr = isoDateFormatter.string(from: Date())` and check if it's the expected output comparing it with the current string input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Martin has mentioned in the comments your date doesn't have the fractional seconds at the end of the string.
Here's the right format:

```
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SSxxxxx"
```

or remove the `withFractionalSeconds` from `formatOptions` array of `isoDateFormatter`, like this:

```
isoDateFormatter.formatOptions = [
    .withFullDate,
    .withFullTime,
    .withDashSeparatorInDate]
```

Update: As @Leo has mentioned in the comments the use of `Z` for time zone's format is wrong here, it needs to be `xxxxx` instead.

Comment: Thanks.  Why is this format correct and the one that I have is wrong?

Comment: it's because you're specifying that the input has fractional seconds

Comment: @user1107173 You shouldn't set the DateFormatter's  timezone to current. The `Z` in the date string means that the date timezone is UTC. You should set it to `TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)` and set the locale before setting the other properties

Comment: Note also that the timezone is represented as +00:00 while if you use `Z` it represents it as `+0000`. What you need is to use `xxxxx` instead of `Z`. So first set the locale to `"en_US_POSIX"`, then set the timezone to `TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)` and  set the dateFormat to `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxxxx"`. This way if you create a string from the date that you are parsing it will be exactly the same as your input.

Comment: @Frankenstein The use of `Z` for the timezone is wrong here. It will use `Z` instead of `+00:00` to represent the UTC timezone while the original date string doesn't. So this will create a string like `2020-07-08T16:33:37.228Z`instead of `2020-07-08T16:33:37.228+00:00`

Comment: For more info about dateFormat timezone settings you can check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkYVY.png. The timezone that the OP needs is the ones "without Z for 0"

Comment: @user1107173 BTW when using ISO8601DateFormatter there is no need to set the timezone to 0 secondsFromGMT. It is its default value. And AFAIK there is no way to create a string without Z for 0 using ISO8601DateFormatter.

Comment: @LeoDabus Oh, I referred a website for getting the date format, maybe I got it wrong. Will surely update my post with your corrections. Thanks mate!

Comment: @Frankenstein The funny thing is that if you look at Apple's doc it says that `.withInternetDateTime` would result in `2016-06-13T16:00:00+00:00` but it actually results in `2016-06-13T16:00:00Z`  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter/1643324-formatoptions

Comment: @LeoDabus Maybe the documentation needs to be updated or someone has made a mistake. I updated the format with your suggestions hope it's right now.

Comment: It would probably parse it successfully but when creating the string it would not be the same as expected

Comment: Yeah, I posted this after trying it out on playgrounds if it had failed I would have gone deeper to find the right format.